# clr.AddReference and clr.ImportExtensions give an "expected type, got str" error

Tags: .net, ironpython

I can't seem to add a reference or import any extension methods in my IronPython scripts. For instance, with this script from one of my unit tests:

```
import clr;
clr.ImportExtensions('FrEee.Utility.Extensions');
from System import Math;
x * y
```

I get the error "expected type, got str". I tried removing the quotes from 'FrEee.Utility.Extensions', and changing them to double quotes, but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

(For reference, the values for x and y are injected into the script scope by the unit test.)

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I figured it out.

I needed to import the namespace containing the extension methods as a module, and pass the module into clr.ImportExtensions. I also needed to use clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath to load the DLL containing the code I wanted to import.

```
import clr;
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath('FrEee.Core.dll');
from FrEee.Utility import Extensions;
clr.ImportExtensions(Extensions);
x * y
```